# how to get width, height or tinymce editor

Tags: jquery, tinymce

i'm trying to get width and height of tinymce editor.

i'm trying to set width and height of textarea fit with rich text editor.

tried with jquery, but default it returns width=100px only :|

```
setup : function(ed) {
        // Add a custom button
        ed.addButton('bbcodemode', {
            title : 'View BBcode source',
            image : '{link}/tiny_mce/themes/advanced/img/bbcodemode.gif',
            onclick : function() {
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "{link}/htmltobbcode/",
                    data: "ctn="+encodeURIComponent(tinyMCE.activeEditor.getContent()),
                    success: function(msg){
                        $('#post_content').val(msg);
                        //tinyMCE.activeEditor.setContent(msg);


                    }
                });

                alert($('#post_content_ifr').width());
                $('#post_content').css("width",$('#post_content_ifr').width());
                $('#post_content').css("height",$('#post_content_ifr').height());

                // Add you own code to execute something on click
                tinyMCE.execCommand('mceToggleEditor',false,'post_content');


            }
        });
    }
```

Comment: I was just looking for that, `ed.container.clientWidth`

Answer (score 2):

If the height and width of your editor have been set in the tinymce configuration you are able to get those settings from there using

```
tinymce.get('post_content').getParam('height');
```

and

```
tinymce.get('post_content').getParam('width');
```

Answer (score 1):

`$(tinyMCE.activeEditor.getContainer()).height()`

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you execute the function after it has initalied? Couse this works for me:

```
$("#content_ifr").width()
```

I get 682 when I execute the above code in the console on this page:
http://www.tinymce.com/tryit/jquery_version.php

Comment: doesn't work. the first run. it returns 100px only. but actually it's 100% :| i don't know why. using jquery 1.6.2

Comment: i just update my full code. i'm making switch from bbcode mode to html mode. and get width doesn't work , always init with 100px :(